# Finding the shortcut a Windows program was invoked from

Tags: windows, winapi, shortcut

Is there a way for a Windows program to find out what shortcut (i.e. .lnk file), if any, it was invoked from, so that it can pick up the shortcut's icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`GetStartupInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx) to fill a [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331.aspx) structure. If the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag is set, the `STARTUPINFO::lpTitle` field contains the path to the `.lnk` file.

(This was [undocumented](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess) for a long time. It probably works all the way back to Win95).

Comment: D'oh, I had looked at the STARTUPINFO documentation, but overlooked this. Thanks very much!

Comment: In C# this works correctly using P/Invoke, however I was wondering if there is another way to get the value of lpTitle without calling the native GetStartupInfo method. Something like a propery of Application or Environment?

Answer (score 0):

See this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharplanguage/thread/31cc117e-7726-475c-b9e4-b8041409ce85

I think cmd line params are the only way.