# Determine if process started from shortcut

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to determine if another process/window was started using a shortcut? The purpose being to then read that shortcut to obtain the startup settings: start-in folder, run as admin, etc. Maybe there is a way to find out the catalyst/caller of the program (User/Application w admin privileges/shortcut)?

I'm aware of using the Windows Driver Kit to [determine it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297878/get-startupinfo-for-given-process). Although this is rather tricky to develop in among other things.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to start a process with elevated rights and custom command line. User could use a console, services are executed by the SCM, etc. Your linked approach is the best, and it does not require DDK usage, you could define all Native API functions and structures yourself, the are plenty examples.

Comment: You could, alternatively, just probe your applications environment: The current folder will be the start-in folder, you will have an admin security token (or not) etc.

Comment: There is no reason to check for the link. The startup folder is the current working directory when your program starts. Running is admin, can be determined if your process owns the appropriate token. I can see no need at all to look for the lnk file...

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to determine if another process/window was started using a shortcut?

Yes, but not easily.

As mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6831819/65863) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825869/), a process can find out if itself was started by a shortcut by calling `GetStartupInfo()` and  checking for the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag.  This is documented on MSDN:

[GetStartupInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx)

> Retrieves the contents of the `STARTUPINFO` structure that was specified when the calling process was created.

[STARTUPINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx)

> dwFlags
>   A bitfield that determines whether certain `STARTUPINFO` members are used when the process creates a window. This member can be one or more of the following values.
>
> ...
>   STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME
>   0x00000800
>   **The lpTitle member contains the path of the shortcut file (.lnk) that the user invoked to start this process**. This is typically set by the shell when a `.lnk` file pointing to the launched application is invoked. Most applications will not need to set this value.

Once you have the path to the `.lnk` file, you can parse it using the [`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950.aspx) interface as needed (see [Shell Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx) for more details).

Now, that being said, you cannot *directly* retrieve the `STARTUPINFO` structure of *another process*.  However, you can retrieve it *indirectly*, by injecting code into the target process (using [`CreateRemoteThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx) or [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)), and then have that code call `GetStartupInfo()` and communicate the desired information back to your process using an [IPC mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx) of your choosing (`WM_COPYDATA`, named pipe, mailslot, socket, COM, RPC, etc).

Or, there is an unofficial way (subject to OS version) to get many of the same `STARTUPINFO` field values, including the `.lnk` filename, without injecting any code into the target process.  Use [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280.aspx) to get a pointer to the target process's [`PEB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx)<sup>1</sup> structure, which has a `ProcessParameters` field that is a pointer to an [`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813741.aspx)<sup>1</sup> structure, which has a `WindowTitle` field (amongst other fields that contain values from `STARTUPINFO`).  You can use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to get a `HANDLE` to the target process (you can get the process ID of an `HWND` using [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx)), and then use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) to read the contents of the `PEB` and `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structures as needed.

<sup>1</sup>: Most of the content of the `PEB` and `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structures are not documented by MSDN, but are documented on http://undocumented.ntinternals.net ([here](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FPEB.html) and [here](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FStructures%2FRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.html)).